# Debugging Karma/Jasmine Tests with Angular 2 in WebStorm

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I'm trying to debug my Angular 2 Tests in WebStorm (2016.3.2). The first thing I tried was just to do it in Chrome Dev tools, but I actually don't see the script files in Sources to be able to set the break point. Note that you can see the script tags in the HTML page, but there's nothing in Sources.

[image: Chrome developer tools capture]

So I did a bit more digging and found you can set up WebStorm to [run and debug unit tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/running-unit-tests-on-karma.html#d207666e171).

The tests do run, but the WebStorm breakpoint is never hit, and something seems to be "off" about what is happening. Obviously, I haven't used WebStorm before to run or debug unit tests, so I don't know what normal looks like.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm sure I'm just missing something, but with so many unfamiliar technologies coming together, I'm not sure what thread to pull.

Comment: if you can't see your files in Sources tab of Dev Tools, it means that they aren't loaded in VM; you won't likely be able to debug them in Webstorm as well. Something must be wrong with your configuration. Also, your tests don't seem to be executed, responses re rejected by Chrome because of unknown MIME type - don't you care about it?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be an artifact of Webstorm. I'll write up what I found in an answer.

Comment: No, it's very unlikely that this is a WebStorm issue. Looks like the server application is hosted on (or another server involved in ajax, etc.) sends the response header "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" for security reasons, and this makes the browser block execution of scripts with unknown MIME type

Comment: It's not hosted on a separate server. It's just launched by pressing the little bug button in Webstorm. I presume that launches a different server than "ng test" from the Terminal does (since that error doesn't happen with ng test), but what specifically happens there is being done by webstorm. So, yes, it's exactly related to Webstorm. There's possibly a setting in Webstorm to fix this, but I haven't found it.

Comment: there are no settings in WebStorm that affect this. 'Little bug button' just runs the currently selected run configuration in debugger... If it's a karma run configuration, it runs karma passing your karma.config.js to it - that's all. `ng test` does the same - but it builds your project first

Comment: It's clearly doing something different, but I'm not privy to what the internals of Webstorm look like.

Comment: no WebStorm internals are involved here

Comment: Somehow there's an error happening when Webstorm debugs that doesn't happen from ng test. Must be magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had edited my karma config file to include the ts files and the map files. When I set them both to include=false and launch from the terminal with ng test, the Sources window looks more like this:
[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

This is what I was seeing before, but it confused me because I was expecting to see my own files. However, if I search in that file, I find my own code:
[image: My code in test.ts file]

It still doesn't stop on the break point, but it's a start.

When I try to debug it through Webstorm, it still is seeing the Mime type as video/mp2t, so I'm guessing that it is interfering somehow with the Mime Types set up in the Karma config file.

I find myself wondering if the devs working on this Framework build anything *other* than Frameworks, since at every turn it seems like they've erected huge, unnecessary barriers to actually seeing what's going on in your app.

## Update:

It looks like this is a [bug that comes and goes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1519) in Angular-CLI. Seems to be in the "comes" phase today.

## Update 2

You can find the files in the webpack:// folder that's next to the localhost://folder. It's logical to think that the files you need will be in the apparent site root, but they're not.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious as to why my answer was down voted. It may not get someone all the way to a solution, but at least it's progress and information they wouldn't have to find through their own experimentation.